# Loading image in FabricJs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, fabricjs

I am working with FabricJs in which I am designing a web template. I have one requirement to show the loading image while canvas is loading objects (multiple images and drawing objects). 
But I am unable to find an event which render after all object get loaded on the canvas. Could you please suggest me some solution?

Thanks in advance.
Saloni

Comment: Are you loading multiple objects on canvas at a time?

Comment: yes, the Canvas object has a few images and drawing elements (textboxes, shapes etc) which are being loaded from database in JSON format.

Comment: Have you tried `after:render` event?

Comment: Yes, but the after:render event gets called after rendering each object. I have a requirement to get to know when all the objects are loaded (entire Canvas has been loaded).

Answer (score 2):

You have one way to achieve this task is that you can loop through all json object and add them one by one and after adding them to canvas, don't call `canvas.renderAll()`. you have to call `canvas.renderAll()` after loop is completed. this way `after:render` will get fired only once after all objects are loaded to canvas.
You can look to this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/a6zuy11q/8/

Comment: I tried this code but it's not working. Now objects are not being loaded on the canvas. Could you please provide some more information on this.

Comment: do one thing, make working fiddle of your problem and i will solve it

Comment: I put my code snippet in fiddler at

http://jsfiddle.net/a6zuy11q/2/.

I want to hide the loading image after render complete canvas.

Comment: It does not suite to my requirement. My requirement is when I load some heavy images like SVG images which contains a list of other images and drawing object on canvas then these object take longer time to completly render on canvas. In mean while of time, I want to show loading image that show application working fine and wait until render complete.

Comment: I dont what is not suitable to your requirement. but it is even working for my purpose and it is the same as you. i am also loading SVG file in my canvas of size more than 3MB and it is working like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Please check if it helpful for you, canvas.loadFromJSON has the callback function, hide the loading message
with in the callback.Here is the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mk410jLo/

```
canvas.loadFromJSON(json,function(){
canvas.renderAll();
setTimeout(function(){
$(".loading-bar").hide();
},100);});
```

Comment: I had tried your code but it's not working for me. In my canvas there are number of objects like (images, text etc). Some HD images take some time to load. But loading image hide after 100 millisecond. I want loading image show untill all object full rendered.